# Can I set up different worker process for each domain on my website?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, worker-process

I have ASP.NET website on IIS 7 with a lot of domain bindings.
How can I run separate w3wp.exe (worker process) for each domain name?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to create an application pool for each domain. Because each application pool has its own (can be one or more) worker processes, each domain doesn't share worker processes with other domain.